# How to avoid empty commits and pushes in IntelliJ

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, bitbucket

I have noticed that in internet everyone wants to make empty commits. Well, in my case it's opposite.

For some reason IntelliJ 2022 (and 2023) do it and I want it to stop, but don't know how.

```
16:24:07.797: [..\common] git -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false push --progress --porcelain origin refs/heads/INS-8208:refs/heads/INS-8208 --set-upstream
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Create pull request for INS-8208:        
remote:   https://git.xxx.net/projects/LI/repos/common/pull-requests?create&sourceBranch=refs%2Fheads%2FINS-8208        
remote:
```

Problem is that I have 2 repos under my project and when I do Commit and Push then both repos execute it, even when only one of them has something to commit. Then I have to go into Bitbucket server and delete my empty branch.
I remember times when this was not the case, but I'm not sure if it started after some IntelliJ or Bitbucket update ....

Answer (score 0):

A solution should be:

1. Enable commit pattern check.
2. Define a pattern for your commit messages that, if not matched, will prevent from commit empty messages.

[image: Git configuration]

Comment: I was probably not clear... It is not question of empty commit message, but about empty commit - when nothing was changed and nothing should be commited: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0